# NodeJS Mongoose undefined type in model array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So I have this simple code in my model:

```
objectives: {
    enemies: [
        {
           name: 'Bad Bear',
           health: 556
        }
    ]
}
```

And I get this error: `undefined type Bad Bear at name`. Then my question is how to make more of the enemies in this array without getting the error ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can not use explicit raw value in defining a mongoose model.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use predefined types for mongoose models. Check the docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Try this

```
objectives: {
    enemies: [
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        health: {
            type: number,
            required: true
        }
    ]
}
```